# Brand new SP 2010 setup

Tags: installation

I googled for SP 2010 enterprise setup with sql enterprise and got bunch of links. I would like a good legit link that has been proven to work. Can someone please provide a link that really worked and covers details?

Comment: I am all pumped up. God loosing patience. Can anyone help me with a good n proven link please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still partial to the TechNet information for general planning and process.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667264.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303418.aspx

For user profile sync, there is no better resource than Spence's article
http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Side note.... as pumped as you are, this isn't something to rush.  It needs to be planned well.  If this is just a sandbox that you are using as a test run then give it a try and be ready to dump and reload a couple of times.

Comment: Mike. yes, it's a play area that I need to setup. Thanks